# Does $G\cong H\times K$ imply $H\unlhd G?$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, direct-product

I want to prove the following exercise.

> If a group $G$ is the direct product of subgroups $H,K$, then $K$ is isomorphic to $G/H$.

To prove this, I think I need first to show $H$ is normal in $G$.

I can show that there is a normal subgroup $J$ in $G$ that is isomorphic to $H.$ But I don’t know how to show $H$ is a normal subgroup in $G.$

I’m not sure but my guessing is that $gHg^{-1} = J$ for some $g \in G$, so that $H = J.$ But . . . maybe there’s a counterexample.

Also, if I show $H$ is normal somehow, I still don’t know how the conclusion of the exercise follows from it. When $G = H\times K$ means the internal direct product of its normal subgroups, I can solve the exercise. If not, I know that, by using $\pi_k : H\times K \to K$ (the canonical projection), we can show $H\times K/\ker(\pi_k)$ is isomorphic to $K.$ But how can i show that $G/H$ is isomorphic to $H\times K/\ker(\pi_k)$?

Can somebody help?

Thank you!

Comment: This is actually a lot easier than what you are doing. Just let $G=H\times K$. Then, clearly $H,K$ are both normal in $G$, and are the quotients of the group modulo the other subgroup. The homomorphisms that induce these quotients are simply the forgetful morphisms.

Comment: I think we need to interpret $G = H$ x $K$ as $G$ is isomorphic to $H$ x $K$..

Comment: I don’t understand why H is normal in G clearly.

Comment: Because of the forgetful morphism from $H\times K\to K$.

Comment: If $G\cong H\times K$, there is an isomorphism. You can compose that with the morphism from $H\times K\to K$ to get the desired result.

Comment: Then $H$ x $<e>$ is normal in $H$ x $K$. And?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: What the above posters are saying is: Just remember that normal subgroups are exactly the kernels of homomorphisms. The map $H\times K\to K$ given by $(h,k)\mapsto k$ has exactly $H\times \{e\}$ as a kernel. Use your isomorphism $G\ni g\mapsto (h_g,k_g)\mapsto k_g,$ which now has kernel $H$. Hence, $H$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou, thanks but that’s what I don’t understand. How can i show that the isomorphism send $H$ to $H \times {e}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, if $G$ is the internal direct product of $H$ and $K$, then $H$ and $K$ are both normal, $H\cap K=\{e\}$, and $HK=G$. There is no need to prove this because this is what you are given. Then you can use the relevant isomorphism theorem to show that $HK/H\simeq K/(K\cap H) $.

Comment: So, in the exercise, can I just assume that G is the internal direct product of H and K?

Comment: @anadad If it is the direct product of subgroups, then it is the internal direct product. Even if it's external you can identify the subgroups with $H$ and $K$.

Comment: Thanks. So you mean that whenever I see $G = H \times K$ and $H,K$ are subgroups of G, I can assume $HK=G$, $H \cap K= e$ and they are normal in $G$ ?

Comment: @anadad That is the definition of the direct product.

Comment: Here Matt is talking about the direct product *up to isomorphism*, technically speaking, @anadad; there is a distinction between internal and external direct products - so you're right - and showing that they are isomorphic is often left as an exercise. You can see the difference between them in Gallian's *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra"*.

Comment: Ah, in my book(Hungerford’s algebra), the internal direct product is defined as the weak direct product of subgroups which satisfy the conditions above. And the definition of the direct product is just the (set) product with some binary operation. But the direct product  and internal product are not important because they can be identified?

Comment: @Shaun thanks I will look it up!

Answer (score 0):

The group $G\cong H\times K$ with $H\cong \langle S_H\mid R_H\rangle$ and $K\cong \langle S_K\mid R_K\rangle$ has as a presentation $$G\cong \langle S_H\cup S_K\mid R_H\cup R_K\cup X\rangle,$$ where $X=\{hk=kh\mid h\in S_H\land k\in S_K\}$, from which it is easy to see that $H\cong L$ such that $L\unlhd G$. (Why?)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I don’t know about the presentation.

Comment: You're welcome, @anadad. Nevermind :)